# Cut command to specify the tab as the delimiter

Tags: shell, cut

There is a file  which the delimiter is tab ,when i use the command

```
cut -d \t file.txt  #or  "\t"  or  "\\t"
```

I get this message

> cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields
>
> Try `cut --help' for more information.

How to use the `cut`  command?

Comment: The problem is not the delimiter, but the absence of fields or columns to cut.

Comment: If these aren't working, please show us a sample of the input file so we can compare.

Comment: The delimiter **is** "TAB" by default; however, if for some reason that's not working the way one would expect, specifying the "TAB" character in bash can be achived with:  `cut -d$'\t'` or, perhaps, by hitting Ctrl-v then the TAB key--i.e. `cut -d 'CTRL-v TAB'`.  **NOTE**: instead of simply closing this question, it might be prudent to move it to https://unix.stackexchange.com.  **EDIT**: it seems duplicate already exists at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/how-to-cut-by-tab-character

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Cut splits the input lines at the given delimiter (-d, --delimiter).

To split by tabs omit the -d option, because splitting by tabs is the default.

By using the -f (--fields) option you can specify the fields you are interrested in.

```
echo -e "a\tb\tc" |cut -f 1 # outputs "a"
echo -e "a\tb\tc" |cut -f 2 # outputs "b"
echo -e "a\tb\tc" |cut -f 3 # outputs "c"
echo -e "a\tb\tc" |cut -f 1,3 # outputs "a\tc"
echo -e "a\tb\tc\td\te" |cut -f 2-4 # outputs "b\tc\td"
```

You can also specify the output delimiter (--output-delimiter) and get rid of lines not containing any delimiters (-s/--only-delimited)

```
echo -e "a\tb\tc\td\te" |cut -f 2-4 --output-delimiter=":" # outputs b:c:d
```

If you are interrested in the first field of your input file simply do...

```
cut -f 1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 19):

Default delimiter is '\t' so you just need to execute:

```
cut -f <n> file.txt
```

Where `<n>` is the number of the column

Answer (score 2):

You can try to place a tab between the quotes if you first press " v" then the "" key

```
eg  cat > test.txt 
a    b     c
<ctrl d>

$ grep test.txt | cut -f 2 -d "<ctrl v> <presstab>"
```

will return "b"